# How to find out if a shared hosting is running 32 or 64 bit - with php

Tags: php, linux, cpu

Is it possible to identify Linux 32 or 64 bit, using PHP?

```
phpinfo()
```

returns

```
Linux infong 2.4 #1 SMP Mon Oct 10 09:34:36 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

It's shared hosting so I cant use command line.

Comment: Why does it matter why does it matter? I'ts a question, answer if you can.

Comment: I see that you can't access the command line, but can you still execute shell scripts? Try taking a look at `[shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)`. If you are able to do this, you could easily punch in a shell statement to get it.

Comment: `i686` means it is running in 32 bit mode. Regarding PHP you should rather check PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: `It's shared hosting so I cant use command line.` - a funny one:)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! @tangrs I have program with two versions, and don't know what to install. Don't worry, I don't want to hack CIS server.

Comment: If you are reaching the limits of storing an integer then I would think again about your edesign.

Comment: This is important when using PHP time functions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do a simple test:

```
var_dump(is_int( 9223372036854775807 ));
```

For 32-bit environment it will return false as this number is much bigger that maximum 32-bit integer. For 64-bit environment it will return true.

---

Or use PHP_INT_MAX as mario suggested in comments.

```
echo (PHP_INT_MAX == 2147483647)?'32-bit':'64-bit';
```

---

Or use PHP_INT_SIZE:

```
echo (PHP_INT_SIZE * 8) . '-bit';
```